# Better forecast on seasonal type and lessthan 1 year of data

Tags: forecasting

I have a client which started on december 2014 and they are only capable of sending their sales during middle and last day of the month. I used exponential smoothing to get their forecast sales. The ff is the sample forecast of one of their items with the weighted value of 0.6.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Cutoff Date | Actual Value | Forecast Value
--------------------------------------------------
12-15-2014  |       1      |    
12-31-2014  |       61     |       1
01-15-2015  |       24     |       43
01-31-2015  |       5      |       29.7
```

The forecast value has a big difference to actual value. I read about the seasonal adjustment data from this link https://analysights.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/forecast-friday-topic-forecasting-with-seasonally-adjusted-data/ but it still requires at least a year of data. Is there a way to make the forecast more accurate?

Comment: You could use analogue data/product to capture seasonality. Is this retail industry? If so it is fairly straight forward to get analogue product

Comment: yes it is retail industry, I understand but how does it  affect the computation of the forecast? Should a use multiplier base on the data analogue?